# $f_n:[1,2]\to [0,1]\ni f_n(x)=(2-x)^n,\lim f_n=f$ Then which of the following is true?

Tags: real-analysis

$f_n:[1,2]\to [0,1]\ni f_n(x)=(2-x)^n,\lim f_n=f$

Then  which of the following is true?

1. $f$ is continuous on $[1,2]$

   False definitely
2. $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$

   False , in that case we need $f$ to be continuous as all $f_n$ are.
3. $\lim\int_{1}^{2} f_n dx=\int_{1}^{2} fdx$

   I Cheked that it is true.
4. for any $a\in (1,2)$ we have $\lim f_n'(a)\ne f'(a)$

have no idea.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous in $x$ different from $1$?

Comment: 3 is true right????????

Comment: I suggest you edit your question, since $f_n$ should have domain $[1,2]$.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is $f$ such that $f(1) = 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x\in (1,2]$. So, 1. and 2. are false.

For 3., we have $\displaystyle \int\limits_1^2 f_n = {1\over n+1} \to 0$. Therefore 3. is true.

The function $f$ is differentiable in $(1,2)$. Furthermore $f_n'(x) = -n(2-x)^{n-1} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, assuming $x \in (1,2)$, which implies 4. is false.

Comment: for 3 not 0 to 2 it will be 1 to 2

Comment: as $n \to \infty$   $f_n{'}(x)$ is in $\infty * 0$ form, so can u tell me how you calculate it to be 0. I am applying L'hopital rule but not getting anywhere.